# get status of Leaflet layer control checkbox

Tags: javascript, ajax, leaflet

I have several functions drawing different things on a map using Leaflet and one of them has a layer control which shows/hides some sectors on the map. The other function draw lifts (straight lines).

Upon user action, the content displayed on the map is changed and I redraw the lifts.
I would like the sectors to only be drawn if the user has checked the checkbox but I don't know how to get the value of the checkbox and pass it to the lift function (which should trigger the sector function if the user has checked the checkbox).

How can I save the value of the layer control checkbox and test it in another Ajax function (lift) ?

```
$('#build').on("click", function(e){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: map_controller/show_lift_types",
        success: function(result){
            if (result.returned == true){
                // ... Displays some information in the page 
                drawLift(); // Draws the lifts
                // If the user has chosen to show the sector layer, need to call drawSectors 
                drawSectors();
            }
        }
    });
});


function drawLift() {
    if (typeof lift_path !== 'undefined') {             // If lift_path (the lifts) exists
        map.eachLayer(function (layer) {                // For each layer
            console.log(layer._leaflet_id);
            if (typeof layer._path !== 'undefined') {       // Only if the _path variable exist. Excludes the background image of the map and already built lift
            map.removeLayer(layer);                     // Remove the layer
        }
        });
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: map_controller/get_lifts_map",
        success: function(result){
            for ( i=0; i < result.id_group.length; i++ ) {
                // ... retrieves parameters ...         
                var path_info = {
                    "type": "Feature",
                    "features": [{
                        "type": "Feature",
                        "geometry": {
                            "type": "LineString",
                            "coordinates": [start_location, end_location]
                        }
                    }]
                };
                lift_path = new L.geoJson(path_info,style: style}).on('click', function (e) {
                    // ... Some function...
                }).addTo(map);
            }
        }
    });
};

function drawSector() {
    var sector_path = new Array()   
    var baseLayers;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: map_controller/get_sectors_map",
        success: function(result){  
            for ( i=0; i < result.path.length; i++ ) {
                // ... retrieves parameters ...   
                var sectors = {
                    "type": "Feature",
                    "geometry": {
                        "type": "Polygon",
                        "coordinates": path
                    }
                };
                sector_path[i] = L.geoJson(sectors, style);
            }
            var sectors = L.layerGroup([sector_path[0], sector_path[1], sector_path[2]]).addTo(map);
            var overlays = {};
            overlays[Settings.show_sectors] = sectors;  // Show sector checkbox
            L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlays).addTo(map);
        }
    });
}

// do the actual ajax calls
drawSector(); 
drawLift();
```

**Update:** Based on @davojta suggestion, here is my complete solution:

```
$(document).on('change', '.leaflet-control-layers-selector', function() {
    $checkbox = $(this);
    if ($checkbox.is(':checked')) {
        sectorLayerCheckbox = true;
    }
    else {
        sectorLayerCheckbox = false;
    }
}
```

In `drawLift` I added :

```
if (typeof sectorLayerCheckbox == 'undefined' || sectorLayerCheckbox != false) {  
   drawSector();
}
```

Comment: You might be interested in [Leaflet.ActiveLayers](https://github.com/vogdb/Leaflet.ActiveLayers) plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General algorithm could be the following

- add some meta-data to your checkbox with data-attribites

  ```
  <input id="checkBox" type="checkbox" data-lyftFlag="flagId">
  ```
- listen change invent and make your action after checkbox is checked

  ```
  $('#checkBox').change(function() {
      const $checkbox = $(this);
      if ($checkbox.is(':checked')) {
          const lyftFlag = $checkbox.data("lyftFlag");
          drawLift(lyftFlag);   
      }
  });
  ```

Comment: I've managed to catch the click with `$(document).on('change', '.leaflet-control-layers-selector', function() {` and then store the value with `const lyftFlag = true/false;`

Comment: @remyremy could you provide jsfiddle to take a look and debug?

Comment: I edited my question with the final solution. Thanks for your help it works fine now!